# Use R dplyr to tidy data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

My dataframe `df` looks like this:

```
        Value
X.Y.Z   10
X.Y.K   20
X.Y.W   30
X.Y.Z.1 20
X.Y.K.1 5
X.Y.W.1 30
X.Y.Z.2 3
X.Y.K.2 23
X.Y.W.2 44
```

I'm trying to unpivot using the 3rd character of the row names to name the columns, like:

[image]

So, the row names are now the last character of the rows (after the dot).
I know this is possible to do with `dplyr`, I've tried `gather`, and `spread`, but no luck, can anyone help?

EDIT:
Here's the data above in text, I:

```
structure(list(..1 = c("X.Y.Z", "X.Y.K", "X.Y.W", "X.Y.Z.1", 
"X.Y.K.1", "X.Y.W.1", "X.Y.Z.2", "X.Y.K.2", "X.Y.W.2"), Value = c(10, 
20, 30, 20, 5, 30, 3, 23, 44)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Can you post your data as dataframe format using `dput(df)`? Just run it in your R console and copy the output to your question.

Comment: Please share data in a copy/pasteable format--pictures of data are very difficult to work with. `dput(df)` is a great way to make a copy/pasteable version of a data frame. It would also be great if you showed anything you tried... have you found the `substr` function for extracting a character from a string? Seems like that + `spread` is all that is needed...

Comment: Before you use `spread`, you need to tidy things further using a combination of `rowid_to_column()` and `separate()`

Comment: @Gregor I sure did try substr. The problem is not all row names have the same number of dots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution that seems to work for OP:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
    rownames_to_column %>% 
    transmute(mycols = gsub('^.*\\.', '', gsub('.[[:digit:]]+', '', rowname)),
              myrows = regmatches(rowname, gregexpr('[0-9]+',rowname)),
              value = Value) %>% 
    spread(key=mycols, value=value)
```

```r
  #   myrows  K  W  Z
  # 1        20 30 10
  # 2      1  5 30 20
  # 3      2 23 44  3
```

---

---

#### First Version of my Answer:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(mycols = substr(gsub('.[[:digit:]]+', '', rownames(.)), 5, 5),
         myrows = as.integer(as.factor(substr(rownames(.),7,7)))-1) %>% 
  spread(key=mycols, value=Value)

#>   myrows  K  W  Z
#> 1      0 20 30 10
#> 2      1  5 30 20
#> 3      2 23 44  3
```

***Data:***

```r
df1 <- structure(list(Value = c(10, 20, 30, 20, 5, 30, 3, 23, 44)), 
                 row.names = c("X.Y.Z", "X.Y.K", "X.Y.W", "X.Y.Z.1", 
                               "X.Y.K.1", "X.Y.W.1", "X.Y.Z.2", "X.Y.K.2", "X.Y.W.2"), 
                 class = "data.frame")
```

---

---

#### Update I:

As I said in my comment, we need to clean the data since `$..1` column causes problems for `dplyr`. Here's a solution using the exact data provided in the question:

```r
df1 <- structure(list(..1 = c("X.Y.Z", "X.Y.K", "X.Y.W", "X.Y.Z.1", 
                              "X.Y.K.1", "X.Y.W.1", "X.Y.Z.2", "X.Y.K.2", "X.Y.W.2"), 
                      Value = c(10, 20, 30, 20, 5, 30, 3, 23, 44)), 
                      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
library(tidyr)

clean_names(df1) %>% 
  mutate(mycols = substr(gsub('.[[:digit:]]+', '', x1), 5, 5),
         myrows = as.integer(as.factor(substr(x1,7,7)))-1) %>% 
  select(-x1) %>% 
  spread(key=mycols, value=value)

#>   myrows  K  W  Z
#> 1      0 20 30 10
#> 2      1  5 30 20
#> 3      2 23 44  3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

---

#### Update II:

Couple more approaches to see if they work for OP's dataset. (Without a reproducible example, it's hard, if not impossible, to resolve this; so, these are my final efforts).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
```

```r
df1 %>% 
  rownames_to_column %>% 
  mutate(mycols = gsub('.[[:digit:]]+', '', rowname),
         myrows = regmatches(rowname, gregexpr('[0-9]+',rowname))) %>% 
  select(-rowname) %>% 
  spread(key=mycols, value=Value)
```

or

```r
df1 %>% 
  rownames_to_column %>% 
  separate(rowname,sep = "\\.", into = c("A1","B2","C3", "D4")) %>% 
  select(-A1,-B2) %>% 
  spread(key=C3, value=Value)
```

Comment: if you really have `$..1` column then you can use `janitor` and `tibble` packages and replace `df1` in my solution with ```janitor::clean_names(df1) %>% tibble::column_to_rownames(x1) %>% ...``` the rest stays the same.

Comment: It works with df1 but not with mine. I'm getting the error: Error in rownames(.) : object '.' not found

Comment: thanks a lot, but sitll not working, you may see a sample of the real data at: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u8umbAySKNyuXRph7hc4eYAoJw10niTP/view?usp=sharing I think there's still something wrong with the row names

Comment: @NunoNogueira can you do this `dput(head(your_actual_dataframe,10))` that way we can make sure I can reproduce your error. Otherwise, I may import the csv file and get a different input based on the package I use that for importing. What I have above is the best chance to get a reproducible example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197178/discussion-between-nuno-nogueira-and-m-m).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr) # and tibble is needed, too
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
  mutate(
    type = gsub("(^X\\.Y\\.|\\.[0-9]$)", "", rowname),
    num = gsub("\\D", "", rowname)
  ) %>%
  select(-rowname) %>%
  spread(type, Value)
#   num  K  W  Z
# 1     20 30 10
# 2   1  5 30 20
# 3   2 23 44  3
```

---

BTW, from your question it looks like what you have are proper `rownames`, but your `structure` includes them as a column named `..1`. I thought this might have been an artifact of trying to get the data into your question, so I removed it.

```r
df <- structure(list(..1 = c("X.Y.Z", "X.Y.K", "X.Y.W", "X.Y.Z.1", 
"X.Y.K.1", "X.Y.W.1", "X.Y.Z.2", "X.Y.K.2", "X.Y.W.2"), Value = c(10, 
20, 30, 20, 5, 30, 3, 23, 44)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
rownames(df) <- x$..1
df$..1 <- NULL
```

If this is not quite the case, then you can remove the call to `tibble::rownames_to_column()`. However, having `..1` in a dplyr chain isn't good (`Error: Column 1 must not have names of the form ... or ..j.`), so you'll need to rename it anyway.

Comment: thanks for helping, I think there's still something wrong with the row names, you may see a sample of the actual data here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u8umbAySKNyuXRph7hc4eYAoJw10niTP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If I'm inferring correctly, you have a regex problem. Change the appropriate line to `type = gsub("(^GeneralLedgerAccounts\\.Account\\.|\\.[0-9]$)", "", rowname),` and it works fine.

Comment: If that's the case, Nuno, then there is significantly more in your data than you are letting on. When I tested with the sample you provided in your google-drive link, it generated a 3x10 frame, including columns `AccountDescription` through `TaxonomyCode`. I believe that you are under-representing the variability of your data. I suggest you take perhaps 50 lines of your data and *manually* generate exactly what you need it to look like ... and then look at your row-names to determine what is causing the explosion. I suspect that this is not the structure you need.

Comment: have a look at the 100 rows here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z5pI0Rmd-nU2Jk6qLh6PGwf3Jhwsg98u/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The second line doesn't start with `GeneralLedgerAccounts.Account.` as every other line (in that sample) does. You need to think more about how your data is *currently* structured (it is not sufficient to say `X.Y.Z.1` as that is plainly not true) and how you think it will be structured in the end.